# Python replace function nor working as expected

Tags: python

For the code below I am not replacing anything in the old txt. I am expecting it returns: "Where did my vowels go?"

```
def uncensor(txt, vowels):
    c = 0
    for a in txt:
        if a == '*':
            txt.replace('*', vowels[c], 1)
            c=c+1
    return txt

uncensor("Wh*r* d*d my v*w*ls g*?", "eeioeo")
```

However, I can replace letter if I do:

```
txt = 'Wh*r* d*d my v*w*ls g*?'
vowels = 'eeioeo'
txt.replace('*', vowels[0],1)
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to use the returned value `txt = txt.replace('*', vowels[c], 1)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the result:

```
result = txt.replace('*', vowels[c], 1)
```